# How can I insert a Series into a DataFrame row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c','d'], index=['x','y','z'])
df
     a    b    c    d
x  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
y  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
z  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I also have a Series like this

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(3), index=['b', 'c', 'd'])
s
b   -0.738283
c   -0.649760
d   -0.777346 
dtype: float64
```

I want to insert the Series into a row of the DataFrame, for example the 1th row, resulting the final DataFrame:

```
     a       b          c         d
x  NaN      NaN        NaN       NaN
y  NaN  -0.738283  -0.649760  -0.777346
z  NaN      NaN        NaN       NaN
```

How can I do it? thanks in advance ;)

Comment: I upvoted your question and now you have 15 rep. You're now free to use 40 upvotes a day. For example, you can upvote the answer you selected as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) if need select `index` of `df` by position:

```
#select second row (python counts from 0)
df.iloc[1] = s
print (df)
     a        b         c       d
x  NaN      NaN       NaN     NaN
y  NaN  1.71523  0.269975 -1.3663
z  NaN      NaN       NaN     NaN
```

Or [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) ([`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)) if need select by label:

```
df.ix['y'] = s
df.loc['z'] = s
print (df)

     a         b         c         d
x  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
y  NaN  0.619316  0.917374 -0.559769
z  NaN  0.619316  0.917374 -0.559769
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the series as an array:

```
df.iloc[1,1:] = np.asarray(s)
```

[image: Output]